# Can't get local testing working with BrowserStackLocal.exe desktop app on Windows 10

Tags: networking, browserstack

Browserstack has discontinued its chrome extension for local app testing and has moved to a desktop app/.exe that you have to download to do local testing.

I can't seem to get this working running **Windows 10** and I'm wondering if anyone else has had this problem and resolved it.

When I download and execute their desktop app, it tells me local testing is enabled:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDrIn.jpg

When I then use Browserstack Live to test local development I get an error message saying local testing is **not** enabled and it gives me the option to download their desktop app, which I have and says local testing is enabled:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6yxx.jpg

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the desktop app/.exe, it gives me the same results.

I've confirmed with our network team that I am not behind a proxy which is an option to manage the desktop app (under "advanced settings" in the first screenshot above).

Our network team has also whitelisted all traffic from (asterisk).browserstack.com (the actual asterisk character is stripped here) and they're telling me *"Additionally I watched his traffic on the firewall as he tried to use the browserstack software and no traffic was blocked*

I've also been in contact with browserstack support but have basically been feeding their responses to our network team and our network team's responses back to browserstack.  At the end of the day, I still can't get local testing working.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be happening and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same behavior while setting up Local Testing with the BrowserStack Local Desktop app that was released after the announcement by Google about the end of support for Chrome apps ([Click here](https://www.browserstack.com/question/785)). However, I was able to set-up Local Testing post configuring the proxy server details as mentioned over [here](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/live/local-testing/behind-proxies-firewalls-vpns).

I would suggest checking with your IT team if traffic for *.browserstack.com is being routed via a specific proxy at your end and configuring the proxy details in the 'Advanced Settings' for the desktop app.

In case this doesn't work, do contact [BrowserStack Support](https://www.browserstack.com/contact)